# Eclipse debug variable values don't appear

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm currently coding with Java in Eclipse, and I'm trying to use Eclipse's built in debugger to try and debug my code. However, once I enter debug mode and try to run the program till the breakpoint, the variables aren't showing up in the variable window. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please post a screen shot of this ?

Comment: Try resetting the perspective.

Comment: Also, try debugging a very simple project in a new workspace. Does the problem appear there? Do you see any error logs in the error log view ? The  variables view can be opened or focussed by pressing Alt Shift Q then V. Is this the view you are looking at ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're not in the `Breakpoints` tab as opposed to the `Variables` tab on the top-right window in the Debug perspective. When in doubt, simply go to `Window > Show View > Variables`.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by a rendering bug in Eclipse. Often letting the application run past the breakpoint, then trying to re-run again to the breakpoint fixes the display. Other times you have to restart the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem, I could only see method arguments and `this` members, but not local variables. I was searching in all possible project settings and found out this checkbox ("**Add variable attributes to generated class files**") wasn't checked. Make sure all 3 options (used by debugger) are on :

[image]